# block size difference in ls -s and find -size

Tags: find, ls

I was trying to find the  files in the current directory that are of size 1 block , so first I run the `ls -ls` command which show the number of blocks of each file and here is the output :

```
total 28
0 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   2 Jan  9 01:18 bfile
4 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  95 Jan  5 17:46 file1
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  95 Jan  5 17:46 file1~
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   6 Dec 21 13:41 file2
4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   6 Nov 30 01:35 file2~
4 ----------. 1 root root 115 Dec 21 02:20 filecp
4 -rw-r--r--. 2 root root   6 Jan  9 01:06 fileu
4 -rw-r--r--. 2 root root   6 Jan  9 01:06 fileu2
0 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   0 Jan  9 01:06 fileu2~
```

next I run the following command:

```
find . -size 1
```

which will find the all the files that have the size of 1 block , so i expected that no output will be shown ,but the output was :

```
./bfile
./fileu2
./filecp
./file1
./file1~
./file2~
./fileu
./file2
```

so how is that possible ? the ls showed that no files of size 1 block available , but the find command listed the above files as 1 block size !!

note : the bfile listed above was created using truncate command : `truncate -s 2 bfile` which doesn't have a block size that's weird too .

Comment: Check the manpage to see what each command is actually showing. For find `File uses n units of space, rounding up.` and for `ls -ls` `print the allocated size of each file, in blocks`. The manpage for `find` really goes into the details.

Comment: Indeed, *find* tests the *file size*, whereas the -s option shows how many *blocks are actually allocated* to a file. This is not the same thing. The man page says "it's consistent with the result you get for ls -l", not -s. The filesystem in question seems to allocate a minimum of 4 blocks to a file that contains data.

Comment: @berndbausch, that's true ,but for the find command consider the block size on the disk 512 bytes , so if i have a file with 1 byte and i wanted to show the files that have the size of 1 block , that file will show up . i think different tools deals with block in different way right ?!

Comment: If you have a 1 byte file, -size 1 will find it. -size 1b won't, because the file does not have a size of 1 block. The ls -s command will show that 4 blocks are allocated to that file.